# Amazon boto.mws connection with IAM roles and profiles

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, boto

I've been attempting to connect to Amazon's boto SDK to build a connector to Amazon's MWS service.

However, right now, the only way I've been able to provide my credentials to boto.mws.connection's MWSConnection class is by hardcoding in the access and secret key. Clearly this is not suitable for deployment.

When I've used other Amazon services such as SQS, I've been able to connect using an IAM role and profile. For example, here is some sample code I've used to connect to SQS with a profile:

```
REGION = "us-west-2"
PROFILE_NAME = 'my_profile'

class SQSManager(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = boto.sqs.connect_to_region(region_name=REGION, profile_name=PROFILE_NAME)
```

However, I have not been able to find a method to connect via profile_name for MWS. I've searched through the MWSConnection class' methods, and this is how it instantiates a connection:

```
class MWSConnection(AWSQueryConnection):

    ResponseFactory = boto.mws.response.ResponseFactory
    ResponseErrorFactory = boto.mws.exception.ResponseErrorFactory

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        kw.setdefault('host', 'mws.amazonservices.com')
        self._sandboxed = kw.pop('sandbox', False)
        self.Merchant = kw.pop('Merchant', None) or kw.get('SellerId')
        self.SellerId = kw.pop('SellerId', None) or self.Merchant
        kw = self._setup_factories(kw.pop('factory_scopes', []), **kw)
        super(MWSConnection, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
```

It's clearly accepting the access / secret keys are keyword parameters. Is there anyway to connect to MWS using Amazon's boto SDK using profiles and IAM roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marketplace Web Service (MWS) is Amazon retail. I don't think it's in any way related to AWS and it doesn't use IAM at all. I'm actually surprised to see it supported in boto (it's [not in boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/260)).